# Magento 2 "More" button on poduct listing page

Tags: magento2, product-images, swatches, color-swatches

I want **more** button next to swatches image and on click of **more**, it will redirect to the product details page

Comment: Hello Akshay, did you answer for this? I have to do same functionality

Comment: @Arjun there is configuration store->catalog->storefront set Use Flat Catalog Product-> 
Yes and Show Swatches in Product List -> Yes
To change more link done customisation in vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml

Comment: okay thanks @Akshay